# select a div from a list of divs and toggle class on that div reactjs functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a **functional component** in react that receives an array with numeric values.

For each value I build a div and place them next to each other in a flexbox.

When I click on a div I have to select it by adding or removing the class `selection-bar-selected` which simply changes the color of a bar placed at bottom of the div.

What I did works but it selects all the divs, how can I make it select only the div I clicked?

Here is my code and thanks in advance for the answers.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

const SelezionaTab = () =>{
    selected ? setSelected(false) : setSelected(true);
}


return (
    <div className="months-tab">
        
        {props.data.map((v, k) => 
            <div className="single" key={k} id={"tab-"+k} onClick={SelezionaTab}>
                <div className="single-header">
                    <p className="mese">{k}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="single-body">
                    <div className="value">
                        <p className="numero-spese">{v.doc} doc.</p>
                        <p className="importo">{v.val}</p>
                    </div>  
                    <div className={selected ? "selection-bar selection-bar-selected" : "selection-bar"}>
                </div>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
       
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish which tab is selected in the `selected` state, so for example you can change its value from being a `boolean` to a `number` or `string` that holds the index or name or id of the currently selected tab(s), so:

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});

// This is really `ToggleTab` rather than `SelezionaTab`
const SelezionaTab = (tabId = null) => {
    setSelected({ ...selected, [tabId]: !selected[tabId] })
}

// in the component
onClick={() => SelezionaTab(k)}

// and the selected class becomes:
<div className={selected[k] ? "selection-bar selection-bar-selected" : "selection-bar"}>
```

Comment: yes it works thanks! if i wanted to select more tabs instead of storing only the index do i store an array of index right?

Comment: Yeah right, you can use an array or an object. Then modify the `SelezionaTab` to toggle the state, I'll update the answer

Comment: Definitely use an object (hash) this for the constant lookup.

Comment: perfect, it works thank you very much!
The only thing I think in the control is `selected[k] ? ....` because as it is written now it does not work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The selected state that you are storing could be the id or index of the element. Then when you loop over the list you only change the class when the id or index matches currently selected.

Right now you are only suggesting that there is something selected, but true/false doesn’t tell you which item in the list.

You are very close otherwise.